# View Binding to Switch between activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-viewbinding

Previously I always used intent to switch from one activity to another but now i'm trying to use ViewBinding and I dont know how to use it in replacment of Intent. I'm using kotlin language and XML.

I tried to find a solution video but didn't got any.

Comment: ViewBinding has nothing to do with using Intents or not. You still need to use Intents

Comment: ViewBinding basically replaces `findViewById`, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

We mostly use intent to move from one activity to another activity and it is same as used in kotlin language.View Binding is just bind your view on the activitivies, dialogs, and other custom view.view binding just replacement of

```
findViewById
```

if you want to go another activity so just use this line of code.
**in Kotlin**

```
val intent = Intent(this, clazz)
startActivity(intent)
this.finish() // if you need.
```